# im2txt UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has size zero when run Training when changing new data

Tags: tensorflow

I got an error when I changed new images to train the im2txt model. Don't know why.

```
Build the model.
bazel build -c opt im2txt/...
bazel-bin/im2txt/train 
    --input_file_pattern="${MY_DATA_DIR}/train-?????-of-00256" 
    --inception_checkpoint_file="${INCEPTION_CHECKPOINT}" 
    --train_dir="${MODEL_DIR}/train" 
    --train_inception=false 
    --number_of_steps=10000
```

It went to error when running below sentence

```
sequence_length = tf.reduce_sum(self.input_mask, 1)
lstm_outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell,
    inputs=self.seq_embeddings,
    sequence_length=sequence_length,
    initial_state=initial_state,
    dtype=tf.float32,
    scope=lstm_scope)
```

---

The detail info is below

```
    INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 0
    INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 9.5415 (37.21 sec/step)
    INFO:tensorflow:global step 2: loss = 6.6332 (12.90 sec/step)
    INFO:tensorflow:global step 3: loss = 3.1327 (13.01 sec/step)
    INFO:tensorflow:global step 4: loss = 6.2893 (12.04 sec/step)
    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError'>, TensorArray has size zero, but element shape is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
[[Node: OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3 = TensorArrayGatherV3[_class=["loc:@lstm/lstm/TensorArray_1"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, element_shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/TensorArrayGradV3, lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/range, OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/gradient_flow)]]

Caused by op u'OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3', defined at:
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 155, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 135, in main
learning_rate_decay_fn=learning_rate_decay_fn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/optimizers.py", line 226, in optimize_loss
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 345, in compute_gradients
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 482, in gradients
in_grads = grad_fn(op, *out_grads)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_grad.py", line 186, in _TensorArrayScatterGrad
grad = g.gather(indices)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 328, in gather
element_shape=element_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2226, in _tensor_array_gather_v3
element_shape=element_shape, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in init
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3', defined at:
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 155, in 
tf.app.run()
[elided 0 identical lines from previous traceback]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 89, in main
model.build()
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 437, in build
self.build_model()
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 356, in build_model
scope=lstm_scope)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 546, in dynamic_rnn
dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 664, in dynamic_rnn_loop
for ta, input in zip(input_ta, flat_input))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 664, in 
for ta, input in zip(input_ta, flat_input))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 380, in unstack
indices=math_ops.range(0, num_elements), value=value, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 408, in scatter
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2492, in _tensor_array_scatter_v3
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has size zero, but element shape is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
[[Node: OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3 = TensorArrayGatherV3[_class=["loc:@lstm/lstm/TensorArray_1"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, element_shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/TensorArrayGradV3, lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/range, OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/gradient_flow)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 155, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 152, in main
saver=saver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 793, in train
train_step_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 530, in train_step
run_metadata=run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: TensorArray has size zero, but element shape is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
[[Node: OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3 = TensorArrayGatherV3[_class=["loc:@lstm/lstm/TensorArray_1"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, element_shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/TensorArrayGradV3, lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/range, OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/gradient_flow)]]

Caused by op u'OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3', defined at:
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 155, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 135, in main
learning_rate_decay_fn=learning_rate_decay_fn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/optimizers.py", line 226, in optimize_loss
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 345, in compute_gradients
colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py", line 482, in gradients
in_grads = grad_fn(op, *out_grads)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_grad.py", line 186, in _TensorArrayScatterGrad
grad = g.gather(indices)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 328, in gather
element_shape=element_shape)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2226, in _tensor_array_gather_v3
element_shape=element_shape, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in init
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

...which was originally created as op u'lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3', defined at:
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 155, in 
tf.app.run()
[elided 0 identical lines from previous traceback]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
_sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/bazel-bin/im2txt/train.runfiles/im2txt/im2txt/train.py", line 89, in main
model.build()
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 437, in build
self.build_model()
File "/data/projects/content_creator/image2text/im2txt/im2txt/show_and_tell_model.py", line 356, in build_model
scope=lstm_scope)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 546, in dynamic_rnn
dtype=dtype)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 664, in dynamic_rnn_loop
for ta, input in zip(input_ta, flat_input))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py", line 664, in 
for ta, input in zip(input_ta, flat_input))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 380, in unstack
indices=math_ops.range(0, num_elements), value=value, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 408, in scatter
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 2492, in _tensor_array_scatter_v3
name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)

UnimplementedError (see above for traceback): TensorArray has size zero, but element shape is not fully defined. Currently only static shapes are supported when packing zero-size TensorArrays.
[[Node: OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGatherV3 = TensorArrayGatherV3[_class=["loc:@lstm/lstm/TensorArray_1"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, element_shape=, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/TensorArrayGradV3, lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/range, OptimizeLoss/gradients/lstm/lstm/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3_grad/TensorArrayGrad/gradient_flow)]]
```